# How to Bisect in Blender?

Tags: modeling, bisect

Can anyone please tell me what he is doing? How did he get that cross margin? (white dotted lines) and how can he select all the vertices of one circular line before bisecting them?

[image]

Comment: he selected everything with `a` and then basically did object menu *Mesh > Bisect* (shortcut `Shift+Spacebar+8`) and then click on the left side and drag to the right side then press `Ctrl` while dragging to get a straight line.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much. I can do it after you explained. <3

Comment: cool! enjoy using that tool coz it's awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1` In *Edit Mode*, press <kbd>A</kbd> to select everything.
`2` Go to object menu *Mesh > Bisect* ( or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> ) or long click <kbd>LMB</kbd> [`Knife Tool`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/tools/knife.html):

[image]

`3` Click on the far left side of object and drag to the right side and press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  to strighten line.
`4` Release <kbd>LMB</kbd> to confirm bisection.